# Unodered_map find followed by emplace or just insert for maximum efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, insert, unordered-map

So I've been doing research on the efficiency of the orderings of different unordered_map function calls. Here are two possible workings out of the same code.

Note: keywordMap is an unordered map that maps strings to vector of a home-made struct (which is the type of e). This is done in a loop.

First option:

```
auto curKeyWord = someString;
auto curEntryPair = keywordMap.insert(
     make_pair( move(curKeyWord), vector<entry*>{e} ) );
if (!curEntryPair.second){//insertion failed
       curEntryPair.first->second.push_back(e);
    }
```

Second option:

```
auto curKeyWord = someString;
auto curEntry = keywordMap.find(curKeyWord);
if( curEntry == end(keywordMap) ){//DNE in map
    keywordMap.emplace( make_pair( move(curKeyWord), vector<entry*>{e} ) );
}
else{
    curEntry->second.push_back(e);
}
```

I am interested in which of these blocks of code is faster. The question really boils down to how .insert works. If insert basically works as finding where the key should be and inserting it if it doesn't exist, then the first should be faster, as it is just a single probe. Once I've called insert, I have everything I need to call push_back should the insert not have done anything. It also is, however, significantly uglier. I'm also curious if insert has the same problem emplace does, where it constructs the element before checking whether or not the key exists in the map already.

It is possible that I will have to benchmark these two pieces of code, but I am wondering if there is any piece of information that I am missing that would tell me the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the first bit of code is faster because it performs a singe lookup.

Here is the usual way of doing insert/overwrite in map:

```
auto rv = map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
if (!rv.second)
    rv.first->second = value;
```

The point here is that that `std::map` is usually implemented as a balanced binary tree (google: red/black tree) so both `insert()` and `find()` take O(log(n)) steps. IE the container has a natural internal order and insertion must place the new items at their correct place. (that is why the keys must be in strict weak order).

`std::unordered_map` uses hashing, so the lookup is O(1) for the default-constructed map (ie when there is a single item in every bucket). Once collisions are allowed (ie when you have `k` items in each bucket), each lookup would be take O(k) steps.

Now, going back to the original question - doing less work is always better. The difference in the std::unordered_map case is very small (the second lookup happens in O(1) steps in the default case).

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. So I'm definitely talking about using an unordered_map and I am familiar with the general implementation of both map and unordered_map (and set/uset). The issue I'm having is whether or not the call to insert the first time will do enough unnecessary work to overpower the gain I get from not doing the second lookup. Everything I'm doing here is constant time avg, so the real question is which one is worse.

As I am doing an insertion I construct a vector and I am not sure whether or not it or the pair are actually constructed. If they are I fear that it may be slower